# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4999, 1), indices imply (4999, 1128) when using matmul

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

I wrote pretty basic code in order to practice using matmul function and even though it as simple as possible it does not work.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4999, 1128)))
    tab = np.random.rand(1128)
    np.matmul(df,tab)
```

It gives following errors:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1651, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
        placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))]
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3095, in make_block
        return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 87, in __init__
        '{mgr}'.format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs)))
    ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 1128

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
        np.matmul(df,tab)
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1909, in __array_wrap__
        return self._constructor(result, **d).__finalize__(self)
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 424, in __init__
        copy=copy)
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 167, in init_ndarray
        return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values], [columns, index])
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1660, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
        construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
      File "/Users/jk/Documents/programowanie19/movie_recommendation/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1691, in construction_error
        passed, implied))
    ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4999, 1), indices imply (4999, 1128)
```

Dimensions of two matrices should match - **df is (4999,1128)** and **tab is (1128,1)**. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: What is the reason why you box your data in a DataFrame before you call a numpy version, why not doing the calculations with the raw objects?

Comment: You need to know, that pandas is built on numpy, but it provides data structurs that are not really meant for matrix operations, so can't really expect this to work. Try to use something like `d1= np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4999, 1128))` ;
`d2= np.random.rand(1128)` ; `np.matmul(d1,d2)` instead.

Comment: For me, removing the dataframe makes the example work. Can you confirm whether this is the case for you as well?

Comment: It turned out, that pandas DataFrame was indeed the problem. I used pandas dot instead of numpy matmul and now it works fine, thank you!

Comment: `df @ tab` should also work (`df.dot(tab)` is the same thing - according its docs).  Either way, the pandas controls the calculation.